# How to update a variable to use in another scope

Tags: javascript, scoping

I have a variable let second = 20 that i make 1 lower until it hits 0. When it hits 0 i want to stop running a part of my code but the variable second is always 20 when i use it because i make it lower in another scope. Sorry if my explenation is a bit unclear.

Here is the code:

```
votingEnd = document.querySelector(".imposters__voting");
imposters = document.querySelectorAll(".imposter");
let second = 20;

window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  let myinterval;

  myinterval = setInterval(function () {
    second--;

    if (second < 11) {
      votingEnd.style.color = "red";
    }

    votingEnd.innerHTML = `Voting ends in: ${second}s`;
    if (second == 0) {
      clearInterval(myinterval);
      votingEnd.innerHTML = `Voting has ended`;
    }
  }, 1000);
});

if (second > 0) {
  //second is still 20 here because i lowered it in my function above. How can i solve this
  for (let i = 0; i < imposters.length; i++) {
    imposters[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
      let count = 0;
      while (count < imposters.length) {
        imposters[count++].classList.remove("voted");
      }
      this.classList.add("voted");
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: When should the `if (second > 0) {` block be running?  It appears you reduce `second` once every second-- do you want to run the `if (second > 0) {` block after every decrement?  If so, I would say it belongs inside of the `setInterval` with the rest of your code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the if (second > 0) inside the click function that way it will check for the most recent value of second instead of just once on load like so

```
for(let i = 0; i < imposters.length; i++){
    imposters[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (second > 0) {
        let count = 0;
            while (count < imposters.length) {
                imposters[count++].classList.remove("voted");
                    }
            this.classList.add("voted");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem has nothing to do with scope. It has to do with timing. That last part of your code only runs once, before the interval runs twenty times.

Here's the order of operations:

1. Initialize `second` to `20`.
2. Bind the countdown function to `window.onload`. (This does not run yet)
3. Check if `seconds` is greater than `0`, and it is because the intervals haven't run yet. This is the *only* time this code *ever* runs.
4. `window.onload` is triggered, and your countdown begins
5. one second later, `seconds` is now `19`
6. `19` seconds later `seconds` is not `0`, and the interval is cleared.

So what you need to do is trigger your code *in each iteration of the interval*.

You want something closer to:

```
let second = 20;

window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  const myinterval = setInterval(function () {
    second--;

    // other logic here...

    if (second > 0) {
      countdownTick(); // runs every second with the interval handler
    }

    if (second == 0) {
      clearInterval(myinterval);
      // cleanup
    }
  }, 1000);
});

function countdownTick() {
  // Do the stuff you need to do each second here
}
```

Comment: i worked with the function and ``` if (second > 0) ... ``` like you said but for some reason it does not work.  when i do ```console.log(second)``` inside the if structure. It only shows until 1. It doesn't show 0. So i suppose that means that the computer doesn't enter that part of the code anymore after second hits 0. But why does the function get called either way?

Comment: if you put a `console.log` inside the condition `if (second > 0)` then it will only run when `second` is greater than `0`. So that makes sense. Nothing in that conditional branch will run once it hits zero. A function in your interval would only get call every time if if was outside that conditional.

Answer (score 0):

Your `setInterval` runs every second. That does not mean that the rest of the code also runs every second. Which is why second is still 20 when the code gets to `if (second > 0)`.

So you need to make sure that this part of your code runs every second as well. One solution would be to wrap that code inside a function which you call inside the interval, like this:

```
votingEnd = document.querySelector(".imposters__voting");
imposters = document.querySelectorAll(".imposter");
let second = 20;

window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  let myinterval;

  myinterval = setInterval(function () {
    second--;

    if (second < 11) {
      votingEnd.style.color = "red";
    }

    votingEnd.innerHTML = `Voting ends in: ${second}s`;
    if (second == 0) {
      clearInterval(myinterval);
      votingEnd.innerHTML = `Voting has ended`;
    }
    check();
  }, 1000);
});

function check() {
if (second > 0) {
  //second is still 20 here because i lowered it in my function above. How can i solve this
  for (let i = 0; i < imposters.length; i++) {
    imposters[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
      let count = 0;
      while (count < imposters.length) {
        imposters[count++].classList.remove("voted");
      }
      this.classList.add("voted");
    });
  }
}
}
```